# What does an "Algn" of 2**2 and 2**0 mean in the output of objdump?

Tags: c, elf, objdump

What does this mean in below file? `2**2` and `2**0`

```
$ objdump -h main.o

main.o:     file format elf32-i386

Sections:
Idx Name          Size      VMA       LMA       File off  Algn
  0 .text         0000000b  00000000  00000000  00000034  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, CODE
  1 .data         00000000  00000000  00000000  00000040  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
  2 .bss          00000000  00000000  00000000  00000040  2**2
                  ALLOC
  3 .note.GNU-stack 00000000  00000000  00000000  00000040  2**0
                  CONTENTS, READONLY, CODE
```

Comment: A more generic "explain all headers question": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15862288/readelf-meaning-of-column-headers

Answer (score 10):

I would assume that `2**2` means 2<sup>2</sup>, or 4 byte alignment, while `2**0` means no (one byte) alignment.

This value comes from the `sh_addralign` field of the ELF section header. The [ELF specification](http://www.skyfree.org/linux/references/ELF_Format.pdf) states (emphasis mine):

> `sh_addralign` Some sections have address alignment constraints. For example, if a section holds a
>   doubleword, the system must ensure doubleword alignment for the entire section.
>   That is, the value of sh_addr must be congruent to 0, modulo the value of
>   sh_addralign. Currently, **only 0 and positive integral powers of two are allowed.**
>   Values 0 and 1 mean the section has no alignment constraints.

As [Ray Toal mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21718388/what-does-an-algn-of-22-and-20-mean#comment32842272_21718432), since the alignment must be a power of two, it only makes sense that `objdump` would express this value as a power of two with the `2**x` notation.

Note that in some languages, like [Python](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#the-power-operator) and [FORTRAN](http://www.csee.umbc.edu/~squire/fortranclass/summary.shtml#Oper), `**` is a power or exponentiation operator.

---

Looking at [`objdump.c`](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/gdb/gdb-961/src/binutils/objdump.c), we see:

```
static void
dump_section_header (bfd *abfd, asection *section,
             void *ignored ATTRIBUTE_UNUSED)
{
  // ...
  printf ("  %08lx  2**%u", (unsigned long) section->filepos,
      bfd_get_section_alignment (abfd, section));
```

And in [`objdump.h`](http://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/bounds/include/bfd.h):

```
#define bfd_get_section_alignment(bfd, ptr) ((ptr)->alignment_power + 0)
```

where the `alignment_power` member of `bfd` is:

```
/* The alignment requirement of the section, as an exponent of 2 -
   e.g., 3 aligns to 2^3 (or 8). */

unsigned int alignment_power;
```

---

Comment: No need to assume, [see the ELF format documentation](http://www.tortall.net/projects/yasm/manual/html/objfmt-elf-section.html).  You are, of course, correct.

Comment: @RayToal There's nothing in that link that indicates that `2**2` means 4.

Comment: Okay, true for that link, but seriously it is hard to read "must be a power of two" as anything but license for the `objdump` author to write the alignment in the form `2**`n, though.

Comment: @RayToal Thanks, I totally agree. Just digging for something solid to cite.

Comment: `**` meaning power comes from FORTRAN

Comment: Thanks @ChrisDodd. Can't say I've ever dabbled :-)

Comment: Why is Algn needed at all? Doesn't `sh_addr` already specify where the segment goes into memory? Or is it to specify alignment of things inside of the segment?

Comment: @CiroSantilliOurBigBook.com It's useful for intermediate object files. This communicates to the next stage of linking the required alignment for that section.